# R: Rename coordinates in vector file

Tags: r, dplyr, rename, r-sf, r-sp

I'd like to rename the coordinates of a vector file containing points.

```
head(pts@coords)

coords.x1 coords.x2
[1,]  960772.6   8784075
[2,]  952244.0   8629062
[3,]  969143.5   8790772
[4,]  994527.3   8798867
[5,]  828560.8   8799644
[6,]  887490.3   8600384
```

When trying the following from the spdplyr library:

```
pts <- pts@coords %>% 
  rename(x = coords.x1,
         y = coords.x2)
```

I get the error

```
Error in UseMethod("rename_") : no applicable method for 'rename_' applied to an object of class "c('matrix', 'array', 'double', 'numeric')"
```

How could I rename these coordinates in R?

Comment: Maybe `pts@coords %>% data.frame() %>%` and then rename!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a `matrix`.  We can convert to `data.frame` or `tibble` as the `?rename` suggests

> .data -
> A data frame, data frame extension (e.g. a tibble), or a lazy data frame (e.g. from dbplyr or dtplyr). See Methods, below, for more details.

```
library(dplyr)
pts@coords <- pts@coords %>%
    as.data.frame %>%
    rename(x = coords.x1, y = coords.x2) %>%
    as.matrix
```

---

In `base R`, it is a straightforward process

```
colnames(pts@coords) <- c('x', 'y')
```

Comment: I would then need to convert it back to a matrix? or can I leave it as a data frame and continue working on my spatial analysis?

Comment: @Joehat If you want to assign it back to `pts@coords`, then do the assignment after reconversion